# Limit bandwidth of my WiFi card

Tags: wireless, bandwidth

I am trying to install a vagrant instance while I am sitting in a group on a congress. Since we don't have such a big bandwidth here, I would like to limit the bandwidth of the initial download of the vagrant box.

Is there a simple way how to limit the throughput of my wireless card right now?

Comment: UPDATE: the answer doesn't work, the bandwidth goes down to 0 after a short time

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the duplicate, you can simply use:

```
sudo apt-get install wondershaper
```

In terminal find out what is the name of the interface connected to your internet by using `ifconfig`. Could be eth0, wlan0, etc... In my case is wlan0. So I would do this:

```
sudo wondershaper wlan0 1024 256
```

This will give me a download speed of 1024 Kbits and 256 Kbits upload, which is 128KB and 16KB.

You can reset your card with this:

```
sudo wondershaper clear wlan0
```

**NOTE:** That will limit ANYTHING in your PC, for example the torrent downloader, firefox, etc..